# What is order of play and how does it work?

Tags: terminology, hearthstone

I have been an avid (casual) player of hearthstone since its initial release. While I have played my share of games, I have never bothered to delve deeper into the mechanics of the game.

After watching several hearthstone videos on youtube, I came across the term **"order of play"**. It seems to be somewhat related to the order of which abilities like deathrattle are triggered being determined by the order in which the minions were summoned.

Take for example a situation where a **Dreadsteed** is pit against am **Unstable Ghoul**. Supposing the unstable ghoul is left with one health and it was played first, if you were to use **Whirlwind** as a warrior, would **Dreadsteed** die once or twice?

I am certain that there are better examples than this but I can't seem to think of one as of right now. Perhaps you can provide an example in your answer.

Comment: If I have just been mislead and the term "order of play" does not really exist, please tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What they mean is,  effects with the same priority take place in the order the card bearing that effect entered the battlefield. This means in you example, the Ghoul's Deathrattle would trigger first, and so the Dreadsteed will only die once.

This doesn't only effect Deathrattles, however, You can see that triggers are processed in the same manner if you summon a creature while having out both a Questing Adventurer and Knife Juggler, whichever was played first, will activate first. This can be important in the event your opponent has a card like Explosive Sheep, for instance.

Comment: Will it only die once? Do not forget about that whirlwind I threw down. Shouldn't it die twice?

Comment: @DavidToh Whirlwind will activate, lowering the Unstable Ghoul's and the Dreadsteed's healthes to zero. Then, because Unstable Ghoul was played first, its deathrattle will trigger, dealing an additional damage to everything on the board. Now, the Dreadsteed's deathrattle will be triggered, and a new one will be summoned.